# ExpandableRecyclerAdpater how to make it scroll to the top

Tags: android, expandablerecyclerview

I use ExpandablerecyclerAdapater. Just want the screen to move up from align with parentItem clicked.

I altered the code to force collapse all items before I expand new one.

```
 @Override
    public void onParentListItemExpanded(int position) {

        Object parent = mItemList.get(position);
        collapseAllParents();    // Alternatively keep track of the  single item that is expanded and explicitly collapse that row (more efficient)
        expandParent(((ParentWrapper) parent).getParentListItem());

    }
```

Now I`m doing in main activity

```
mAdapter.setExpandCollapseListener(new ExpandableRecyclerAdapter.ExpandCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onListItemExpanded(final int position) {
                                  mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, 0);


        }
```

But it doesnt scroll. What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: did you got the answer for this? If yes please post it here. i also need same thing.

Comment: I gave up and turned back to Expandable Listview